# How do I implement markdown in Django 1.6 app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, markdown

I have a text field in `models.py` where I can input text content for a blog using the admin.

I want to be able to write the content for this text field in markdown format, but I'm using Django 1.6 and `django.contrib.markup` is not supported anymore.

I can't find anywhere that has a tutorial and runs through adding markdown to a text field in Django 1.6.  Can someone look at my `.py` files and help me implement markdown to my app.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blogengine.models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields display on change list
    list_display = ['title', 'text']
    # fields to filter the change list with
    save_on_top = True
    # fields to search in change list
    search_fields = ['title', 'text']
    # enable the date drill down on change list
    date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

## index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Django Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for post in post %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ post.pub_date }}</h3>
        {{ post.text }}
        {{ post.tags }}
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on what to use with Django 1.7?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thank you for your answers and suggestions, but I've decided to use [markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux).

Here's how I did it:

`pip install django-markdown-deux`

Then I did `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to make sure that my requirements file was updated.

Then I added 'markdown_deux' to the list of INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'markdown_deux',
    ...
)
```

Then I changed my template `index.html` to:

```
{% load markdown_deux_tags %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Django Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for post in post %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ post.pub_date }}</h3>
        {{ post.text|markdown }}
        {{ post.tags }}
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm glad you get this resolved, but you should try the github API really, at least it's far better than markup. I haven't tried markdown_deux maybe it's also a good choice.

Comment: @laike9m I imagine using the API would be fine if you are rendering once when you save to the database. If you're using it in place of the template tag (which is how I think many people used markdown) then it gets complicated.

Answer (score 7):

Ah, I met with the same problem several months ago, and I found the easiest and most robust solution is to use **[Github Markdown API](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/)**.

Here is the code I use for my blog, which I believe will help you more or less. btw I use Python 3 so the encoding part may be different from Python 2.

```
# generate rendered html file with same name as md
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
if type(self.body) == bytes:  # sometimes body is str sometimes bytes...
    data = self.body
elif type(self.body) == str:
    data = self.body.encode('utf-8')
else:
    print("somthing is wrong")

r = requests.post('https://api.github.com/markdown/raw', headers=headers, data=data)
# avoid recursive invoke
self.html_file.save(self.title+'.html', ContentFile(r.text.encode('utf-8')), save=False)
self.html_file.close()
```

My code is hosted on github, you can find it [here](https://github.com/laike9m/My_Blog/blob/master/css3two_blog/models.py)
And My blog is http://laike9m.com.

Comment: Hi laike9m, I like your answer. Where does "self.body" come from? I had a look at your blog on GitHub and it is not entirely clear to me where 'md_file' comes from. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottSkiles md file is defined here: https://github.com/laike9m/My_Blog/blob/master/css3two_blog/models.py#L53, I submit a form where I fill in the raw markdown text, and the text will be saved to a file, which is the md_file. However I don't think this is the main focus of this answer, my whole point is to use GitHub Markdown API, and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You may use substitution of old markup implemented here - https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield

Comment: django-markupfield is not supported on Django 1.7, specifically with respect to migrations.

Comment: It appears to have been updated for django 1.8+ now.