# Enable markdown to render text submitted from a form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

When employ the bootstrap in Django to format the form, it display nicely.

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>
        {{ entry.date_added|date:"M d, Y H:i"}}
                <small>
                    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">
                    edit entry</a>
                </small>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{ entry.text|linebreaks}}
        </div>

    </div> <!-- panel -->
```

However, it can only render my submitted data in plain text like:

[image]

How to enable markdown to render the text in Django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement markdown in Django 1.6 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031406/how-do-i-implement-markdown-in-django-1-6-app)

Comment: There are a lot of libraries like http://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/ .