# Render Markdown to HTML while preserving headers, newlines, etc.?

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

Happy New Year! I have started out my new year by making a resolution to get Markdown rendering to HTML working for my Django blog. I came across Django Markdownify and it is pretty OK! I managed to get my markdown file rendered, via `get_context_data` as described below in [installation and usage](https://github.com/erwinmatijsen/django-markdownify/blob/master/docs/source/install_and_usage.rst):

#### views.py

```
class MarkDown(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'index.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      markdowntext = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/test.md')).read()

      context = super(MarkDown, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['markdowntext'] = markdowntext

      return context
```

#### index.html

```
{% load markdownify %}
{{ markdowntext|markdownify }}
```

Although basic rendering works, there are some major drawbacks. Including:

1. Inability to recognize headers (e.g. `###` in `### My Header` gets stripped completely)
2. Poor handling of new lines (whitespace is not respected in any form, but blockquotes work for newlines (`>`))

These two issues alone are enough to give me pause and seek out an alternative solution for Markdown to HTML in Django. I did open an issue for [the header problem](https://github.com/erwinmatijsen/django-markdownify/issues/15) and I'll wait to hear back. Until then, if anyone can recommend some Django specific workarounds I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief summary of google results on topic:

[Django Integrated](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/markdown/) Markdown Editors - allow editing and previewing markdown and possibly other formats. Maybe not so lightweight. Usually provide best html escaping:

- [django-markdownx](https://github.com/neutronX/django-markdownx)
- [django-mdeditor](https://github.com/pylixm/django-mdeditor)
- [martor](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor)

Django Fields with Markdown support:

- [django-markupfield](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield)

Other:

- use custom js libraries and render raw text manually to markdown with javascript
- use python libs manually (`markdown`, `misaka`, `mistune`, ...) and generate markdown html in django, possible syntax higlightng with `pygments` - more low-level, more configuration, more issues to solve
- [Interesting option to use third-party api to get rendered markdown html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032089/12520350)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.py and it should work fine.

```
MARKDOWNIFY_WHITELIST_TAGS = [
'a',
'abbr',
'acronym',
'b',
'blockquote',
'em',
'h1',
'h2',
'h3',
'h4',
'h5',
'h6',
'i',
'li',
'ol',
'p',
'strong',
'ul'
]
```